colortbl package with lualatex-dev problem multicolumn
I have using This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024). When using colortbl package with lualatex-dev for creating accessibility PDF multicolumn values are print in the PDF (Example : \multicolumn{15}{c}).
My MWE is:
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress,testphase={phase-III,table}, pdfversion=2.0, lang=en-UK, pdfstandard=ua-2}
\DebugBlocksOff
%\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure}
\tagpdfsetup{role/new-tag=rule/Artifact}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=17cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk,xcolor,colortbl,multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagtool{sec-add-grouping}
\ExplSyntaxOn
 \def\@cmidrulea{%
    \multispan\@cmidla
    %?????????? something needed here??
    &\multispan\@cmidlb
    \unskip\hskip\cmrkern@l%
   {%
    {\tl_set:Nn\l__tbl_rowtag_tl{rule}\exp_args:No\tbl_update_multicolumn_cell_data:n {\@cmidlb}}
   \CT@arc@\leaders\hrule \@height\@thisrulewidth\hfill\kern\z@}%
    \hskip\cmrkern@r\cr}%

 \def\@cmidruleb{%
     \multispan\@cmidlb
     \unskip\hskip \cmrkern@l%
    {{\tl_set:Nn\l__tbl_rowtag_tl{rule}\exp_args:No\tbl_update_multicolumn_cell_data:n {\@cmidlb}}%
     \CT@arc@\leaders\hrule \@height\@thisrulewidth\hfill\kern\z@}%
     \hskip\cmrkern@r\cr}%
 \ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\title{An Image-Association-Based Computing Device Authentication Framework}

\author{Brittany L., Priyankan K.}

\affil{The University of Rhode Island, Kingston, RI, USA}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Current computing device authentication often presents accessibility barriers for people with upper extremity impairments.
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
Authentication is the process of proving one's identity (in our case, to a personal computing device) \textit{credential verification}, where a fresh credential is presented (e.g., typing a password or presenting a biometric) and compared to the registered credential from the setup stage to verify the user's identity.

\begin{table*}
\caption{The Number of Attempts Participants Needed to Authenticate Successfully}
{\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule
\textbf{Authentication} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Modality}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Study}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Limitation}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}
\multirow{3}{=}{Something you are} & Biometric & Voice trait & Not evaluated the designed\\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{15}{c|}{\textbf{Attempts needed}}\\
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Session 1}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{ \textbf{Session 2}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Session 3}}\\
\midrule
P-UD1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
P-UD5 & \cellcolor{red!25}3$+$ & 1 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 & \cellcolor{red!25}3$+$ & 1 & \cellcolor{red!25}3$+$ & \cellcolor{red!25}3$+$ & \cellcolor{red!25}3$+$ & 1 & 2 & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}{}
\end{table*}

The purpose of the second study session was to help determine how easy it would be for users to remember their A3C-FA credentials over time.

\end{document}

The above LaTeX file working fine with lualatex filename.tex and not working lualatex-dev filename.tex...
How to do this with lualatex-dev?

Without metadata and tagging it works. So it seems to be an issue with these. You should report it.

you need the table module to enable table tagging.

@UlrikeFischer: Thanks. I have added \DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table} and it's now showing undefined \cline ERROR. How to solve this?

well start by making smaller MWE, M stands for minimal. Do not drop all your code into a question.

and as a side remark: with ua-2 you must use pdfversion=2.0.

for the cmidrules you could try the fix here https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/issues/69

@UlrikeFischer: I have tried your solutions and didn't work correctly. Any possibility to work \cmidrule?

if you want help than start to make proper complete, minimal examples. How should I know what you have done and what "didn't work correctly" should mean?

@UlrikeFischer: I have updated the sample latex file. It's working fine when using lualatex filename.tex without any errors, but using with lualatex-dev it's showing compilation ERROR.

sorry but why on earth did you add another unsupported package?? remove the multirow. Beside this you forgot the \makeatletter before the redefinitions. And make in future your examples smaller. A tabular with 15 columns is not minimal.
